# Why is MySQL not using my PRIMARY index on a large table?

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

I have a query like this:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT b.* FROM bills b WHERE
(b.id IN (SELECT u.id FROM bills u WHERE u.updated BETWEEN '2023-12-19 14:17:48' AND '2023-12-19 14:27:40' AND u.organisation_id = 'ABC123')
OR b.id IN (SELECT c.id FROM bills c WHERE c.created BETWEEN '2023-12-19 14:17:48' AND '2023-12-19 14:27:40' AND c.organisation_id = 'ABC123'))
```

but the result is

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | t0 | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 10402901 | 100 | Using where |
| 3 | SUBQUERY | c | NULL | range | PRIMARY,organisation_created | organisation_created | 41 | NULL | 1 | 100 | Using where; Using index |
| 2 | SUBQUERY | u | NULL | range | PRIMARY,updated,organisation_created | updated | 5 | NULL | 4 | 1.87 | Using index condition; Using where |

can anyone help me understand why the `PRIMARY` index (which is only on `id`) is not being used in the first row? I tried forcing that index to be used with `FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY)` but it still wasn't used. Also, is it possible to re-write this as a single query that will run faster with JPA (so `UNION` is unfortunately not available)?

Edit:
It seems I should have mentioned that I'm currently re-writing this as a more complex version of

```
SELECT b.* FROM bills b WHERE
(b.updated BETWEEN '2023-12-19 14:17:48' AND '2023-12-19 14:27:40'
OR c.created BETWEEN '2023-12-19 14:17:48' AND '2023-12-19 14:27:40')
AND c.organisation_id = 'ABC123';
```

Second edit:
It seems I should have also mentioned that I have indexes on `(updated)` and `(organisation_id,created)`. I thought these weren't relevant because my sub queries are using them correctly, but in the previous version of the query, because of the `OR` condition on two inequalities (`<` / `>`) on different columns, MySQL was unable to make use of the two indexes. It only used one and then performed a either a table scan or a full lookup for all entries with the same `organisation_id` for the other.

Comment: Please see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055). Add the full `CREATE TABLE` statements and any index related statements to your question.

Comment: @Progman I read that. I considered the definition of the table to be irrelevant - suffice to say it contains a `created` date an `updated` date and the primary index is on `id`.

Comment: It also seems to contain at least some indexes named `organisation_created` and `updated`. We can guess what columns those indexes cover, but *why would you make us guess?* Often readers who want to help you will test their solutions before posting. If you make us guess at your table definition, we have a high likelihood of making a solution that doesn't work for your table. That wastes our time and yours.

Comment: Fair, but those are already being used correctly so there's no question around them, apologies if that info would have been helpful. My question is only regarding the `id` index which I expected to be used after the subqueries worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Query can be simplified because id is a PK and you selecting ids from the same table, you do not need subqueries here.

```
SELECT b.* FROM bills b 
 WHERE

 (b.updated BETWEEN '2023-12-19 14:17:48' AND '2023-12-19 14:27:40'
 OR 
 b.created BETWEEN '2023-12-19 14:17:48' AND '2023-12-19 14:27:40'
 ) AND b.organisation_id = 'ABC123'
```

Try indexing by created, updated and organisation_id  columns.

Definitely index by organisation_id will be the most efficient

Comment: I was actually refactoring this exact code - I was hoping to solve the problem that I MySQL doesn't use two indexes.

Comment: @mjaggard In these case PK index is not applicable.  try to create other indexes on organisation_id,  created, updated

Comment: Those indexes exist but cannot be used in a single query. I had hoped to optimise by using subqueries and I remain confused as to why the PK is not used once the subqueries have run.

Comment: @mjaggard Probably the optimizer does not consider that index as selective given this query because it is already uses other indexes which are enough and primary is not used because it can not estimate the selectivity. Have you tried to analyze stats?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is overly complicated. Why select the IDs from the table rows and then use these IDs to access the same table rows? This doesn't seem to make sense.

Instead use `OR`:

```
WHERE organisation_id = 'ABC123'
AND ( (created ...) OR (updated ...) )
```

The full query can look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM bills
WHERE organisation_id = 'ABC123'
AND
(
  (
    updated >= TIMESTAMP '2023-12-19 14:17:48' 
    AND 
    updated <  TIMESTAMP '2023-12-19 14:27:41'
  )
 OR
  (
    created >= TIMESTAMP '2023-12-19 14:17:48' 
    AND
    created <  TIMESTAMP '2023-12-19 14:27:41'
  )
);
```

The problem with this: Do we want an index on (organisation_id, created) or on (organisation_id, updated)? Or have both timestamps in the index, but if so in which order?

Ideally we would create the first two mentioned indexes and the DBMS would use both.

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON bills (organisation_id, created);
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON bills (organisation_id, updated);
```

But often the DBMS optimzer doesn't see this simple solution. We can help it see the task in a different light:

```
SELECT * 
FROM bills
WHERE organisation_id = 'ABC123'
AND updated >= TIMESTAMP '2023-12-19 14:17:48' 
AND updated <  TIMESTAMP '2023-12-19 14:27:41'
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM bills
WHERE organisation_id = 'ABC123'
AND created >= TIMESTAMP '2023-12-19 14:17:48' 
AND created <  TIMESTAMP '2023-12-19 14:27:41';
```

Comment: The simple version is what I had originally. I can't use UNION due to my ORM not supporting it.

Comment: Well, standing in the way seems to be one of the main objectives of ORMs. :-(

Comment: Indeed. I've re-written this code now to execute multiple queries but it's definitely non-ideal and I still remain confused as to why MySQL can't use the `id` index in my attempt to optimise by using subqueries.

Comment: @mjaggard Which columns are other indices consist exactly?

Comment: I have added the indexes to the question, however they are irrelevant. My actual question is "Why is the index on `id` not being used when my subqueries are working fine?"

Answer (score -1):

**Why not using PK?**

The only way MySQL knows to perform

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE (...) OR (...)
```

is to do a 'full table scan'.  Your attempt to get the `id` values and then load `*` was thwarted by `OR`.  So, let's work on avoiding that formulation.

**Without UNION** -- As leftjoin says,

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  bills
    WHERE organisation_id = 'ABC123')
      AND (   created BETWEEN '2023-12-19 14:17:48' AND '2023-12-19 14:27:40'
           OR updated BETWEEN '2023-12-19 14:17:48' AND '2023-12-19 14:27:40'
          )
```

And have

```
INDEX(organisation_id)
```

That formulation will use that one query reasonably efficiently.  Having two indexes (and changing the query formulation) is unlikely to help performance.

This *may* help a little:

```
INDEX(organisation_id, created, updated)
```

**With UNION** -- Depending of the distribution of the data, Thorsten's `UNION DISTINCT` and two indexes *may* be faster, but I doubt it.  Note that `UNION` (aka `UNION DISTINCT`) must store intermediate results to a file, then de-duplicate.

That is, the query benefit from the two indexes can be used, but the extra overhead of `UNION DISTINCT` may wipe out the benefits.

Comment: Sadly that doesn't answer the main question (why isn't my Primary index being used?) and the index you gave won't help because I have hundreds of thousands of rows per organisation id and the index on created and updated won't help any more than just on created because of the inequality.

Comment: @mjaggard - I added a "why".